# MYSQL: used variable on IN condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

EDIT] The query below is not the actual query which I am having issues with performance. It is only a simplified query. As I only would like to know if it is possible to store multiple results into a variable and used that variable into the IN condition.

I had this query below inside a procedure  which I would like to change for optimization.

```
SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (SELECT facility_id FROM facility);
```

What I would like to do was to store the subquery into a variable and used that variable on the main query.

```
SET @facilities = (SELECT facility_id FROM facility);

SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (@facilities);
```

But I got an error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`.
How should I do it?
Any help is appreciated.

I have found some link that suggest that way http://www.mysqlperformancetuning.com/how-to-speed-up-mysql-by-optimization?nocache=1#comment-961. But I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function to produce a comma-delimited list of values:

```
SET @facilities = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(facility_id) FROM facility);
```

The result will be just a string value, however. If you use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (@facilities);
```

you cannot expect to get a match on every ID in the `@facilities` list. This is because `@facilities` is not expanded into a list and instead is treated as a single item of the IN list. The commas inside it will be seen as just characters inside a string value, not as syntactic delimiters.

In order to use `@facilities` the way you want, you will have to build and execute a dynamic query *around the value* of `@facilities`. It could be something like this:

```
@stmt = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (', @facilities, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This way the query will not contain a reference to `@facilities` – instead, it will have the *contents* of `@facilities` as its integral part, and the commas will thus be treated as part of the syntax.

Each query that you want to use the `@facilities` list in would have to be executed in the above manner. I think you will agree it is not very convenient. There are other considerations to keep in mind as well. When you use a dynamic query and concatenate the contents of a variable into the dynamic query as described, you may be open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also, with a large number of items in an IN list the performance [may degrade](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/).

I would suggest that instead of a variable you use a temporary table to store the IDs:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_facilities AS SELECT facility_id FROM facility;
```

A table is much more flexible in that you are not tied to just one syntactic structure. Although you could still use the temporary table in an IN predicate, as in your example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  request
WHERE
  facility_id IN (
    SELECT facility_id FROM tmp_facility
  )
;
```

you could also use it in an EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  request AS r
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tmp_facility AS f WHERE f.facility_id = r.facility_id
  )
;
```

or in a filtering join:

```
SELECT
  r.*
FROM
  request AS r
  INNER JOIN tmp_facilities AS f ON f.facility_id = r.facility_id
;
```

Having many options how to write your queries may be beneficial when you need to tune them for performance.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but there is another pretty simple option, FIND_IN_SET():

```
SELECT group_concat(facility_id) into @facilities
   FROM facility;

SELECT * FROM request WHERE FIND_IN_SET(facility_id, @facilities);
```

One thing to note about this option is that while it is easier to write than using a TEMP TABLE, efficiency will depend on your use case since FIND_IN_SET often does not play well with indexes. With large data sets, you would probably be better off creating a TEMP TABLE with indexes. On small data sets, the difference is usually negligible and possibly faster without an index.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
Drop temporary table if not exists t1;
create temporary table t1 SELECT facility_id FROM facility;
SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (select facility_id from t1) ;
```

Comment: I would like to remove the subquery on IN() condition. And replace it with variable. Not sure it is possible though.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible the way you have it. The variable can only contain one value.

You might concat all the IDs to a comma separated list (still one string variable, not an array) and then use find_in_set() in the second query. But that will be too slow (no index used in the second query).

You might use dynamic sql - prepare the statement of the second query to "inject" the string into the IN list. But thats cumbersome.

Both of those can and will fail if you try to store too many IDs in the variable.

You should rewrite that query to use a join instead of a subquery (or newer MySQL can optimize that automatically).

If you MySQL version does not optimize it, then you can use a trick in some cases:

```
SELECT * FROM request
WHERE facility_id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT facility_id FROM facility) tmp);
```

That will change the dependent subquery into a derived table which can be evaluated only once instead for each row of the outer query.

And you should check the actual query plan with [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) so you can see what it is doing now and how it changes.

The "suggestion" you tried to use might work well, but only for some specific cases - the ID returned must be single value only and the schema/design does not allow for a simple join.

Answer (score -2):

this problem happen because your **sub-query return multidimensional array** and IN function has argument in single dimensional array.